# How to move Org to new host on hyperledger fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Please help me! Now, I have a network hyperledger fabric includes 2 orgs deploy to 2 hosts. (orgA on host A and orgB on host B). Now I want to change host A to host C. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Your question is too broad here ... what have you actually tried to do?  What issues are you having?

Comment: Now, I am deploying one Org on host A. But I want to move all data from host A to host C.  Host A includes 1 Org(1 Ca, 1 peer0-anchor peer, 1 peer1, 1 couchdb, and 1 chaincode).

Comment: And how are you running each "org"?  Are you using Docker for all of the components?  Did you use persistent volumes?

Comment: Yes, let's say if we have org1 deployed on host A using Kubernetes along with persistent volumes then I wish that, this entire organization be migrated to completely different host (which would also be using Kubernetes and persistent volumes) then what is the standard way of doing so? And also let's assume in place of org1 being peer org, it is an orderer organization (in Kafka mode) and target host makes use of only RAFT OSN, then how to achieve that migration?